# Find three consecutive numbers greater than threshold group-wise in R

Tags: r

How can I get the index of the sample whose previous samples were consecutive and were greater than a fixed threshold in groups?

In the below example, I need to find the `time` when I have consecutively `3 samples` whose speed is greater than 35 `speed >= 35` group-wise

```
speed_threshold = 35

Group   Time    Speed
1       5       25
1       10      23
1       15      21
1       20      40 # Speed > 35
1       25      42 # Speed > 35
1       30      52 # Speed > 35
1       35      48 # <--- Return time = 35 as answer for Group 1 !
1       40      45
2       5       22
2       10      36 # Speed > 35
2       15      38 # Speed > 35
2       20      46 # Speed > 35
2       25      53 # <--- Return time = 25 as answer for Group 2 !
3       5       45
3       10      58 # <--- Return time = NA as answer for group 3 !
```

Comment: if such case arises, we pick the first three consecutive `speeds >= 35`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's above the threshold and it's the third such value in a row, capture the index in `ends`. Select the first index in `ends` and add one to get the index of the return time. (There may be more than 1 such group of 3 and therefore more than one element of `ends`. In this case, the first end needs to be used.)

Note: In your example, the speed at return time is always above the threshold. This code does *not* check that as a condition at all, but simply gives the first `time` after three rows with speeds above threshold (regardless of whether the speed at that time is still above the threshold).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

speed_thresh <- 35

df[, {above <- Speed > speed_thresh
      ends <- which(above & rowid(rleid(above)) == 3)
      .(Return_Time = Time[ends[1] + 1])}
   , Group]


#    Group Return_Time
# 1:     1          35
# 2:     2          25
# 3:     3          NA
```

Data used:

```
df <- fread('
Group   Time    Speed
1       5       25
1       10      23
1       15      21
1       20      40 
1       25      42 
1       30      52 
1       35      48 
1       40      45
2       5       22
2       10      36 
2       15      38 
2       20      46 
2       25      53 
3       5       45
3       10      58 
')
```

Comment: thanks ! the main struggle was to get the time value in the next timestamp. Thanks for the simple solution :)

Comment: The older version of `data.table` does not have the function `rowid`, how can I substitute `rowid` with other functions, I have tried `seq_along` and other things to get the row number but unable to do so

Comment: In that case you can use this function instead `rowid2 <- function(x) ave(x, x, FUN = seq_along)`

Comment: how can I do this in a particular window, for example, I want to search for consecutive numbers greater than the threshold within a window i.e. from the 3rd element to the last element in all groups?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use `rleid` to create a grouping variable based on the logic in 'Speed' and `filter` the rows where the number of rows (`n()`) is equal to 3 and `all` 'Speed' is greater than 35

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df1 %>%
  group_by(Group, grp = rleid(Speed > speed_threshold)) %>%
  filter(n() >= 3, all(Speed > speed_threshold)) %>%
  slice(1:3)
```

Comment: this worked, thanks a lot, I was actually struggling to get the value of time in the next timestamp after the three consecutive samples, which has been also solved in the next answer. appreciate your quick response :)

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Using DF defined reproducibly in the Note at the end, define a function `ok` which takes a vector of logicals indicating whether speed is greater than 35 and returns a logical vector of the same length which is TRUE for the first speed that comes after 3 consecutive TRUEs.  Apply that to each group using `ave` and subset `DF` down those rows which are TRUE giving `s`.

If just returning the groups which satisfy the condition is sufficient then we are done; otherwise, define `Groups` as a one column data frame with one row per Group and merge that with `s` so that we get an NA for those groups not satisfying the condition.

```
library(zoo)

ok <- function(x) cumsum(rollapplyr(x, list(-(1:3)), all, fill = FALSE)) == 1
s <- subset(DF, ave(Speed > 35, Group, FUN = ok))

Groups <- data.frame(Group = unique(DF$Group))
merge(Groups, s, all.x = TRUE)[1:2]
##   Group Time
## 1     1   35
## 2     2   25
## 3     3   NA
```

**2)** A second approach is to split `DF` by group and then perform the calculation over each component of the split.

```
library(zoo)

calc <- function(x) {
  r <- rollapplyr(x$Speed > 35, list(-(1:3)), all, fill = FALSE)
  c(which(cumsum(r) == 1), NA)[1]
}
sapply(split(DF, DF$Group), calc)
##  1  2  3 
## 35 25 NA
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "Group   Time    Speed
1       5       25
1       10      23
1       15      21
1       20      40 # Speed > 35
1       25      42 # Speed > 35
1       30      52 # Speed > 35
1       35      48 # <--- Return time = 35 as answer for Group 1 !
1       40      45
2       5       22
2       10      36 # Speed > 35
2       15      38 # Speed > 35
2       20      46 # Speed > 35
2       25      53 # <--- Return time = 25 as answer for Group 2 !
3       5       45
3       10      58 # <--- Return time = NA as answer for group 3 !"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```